# Cannot use two CSS styles for 2 different components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So i have a problem with the css.  I have one login page which has css with styles in it. One of them is for span:

login.css:

```
span {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px;
    color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

and works fine on the login page, but now i have "my profile page " and im using a function from a library (react-drag-drop-files), which makes me a component which has a span element in it

[image]
and as i can see here it is using the login.css file which i have not imported into my React  function. So i cant style only the span in the "my profile" page simply because i have no access to it. I have also tried to make new span style in the myprofile.css but that messed up the span on the login page. So I think I'm trying to find a way how to separate the two files even though they are not connected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem.

Have you tried using a className for the spans in your login page and create a class in css?
By doing this you should be able to modify only the login page spans.

You could also create different css files for each page.

Hope this helps you

If you don't have direct access to those span styles, I imagine you could wrap those spans in a div, if you can do this, you can also give a className to that div and do something like this in CSS:

```css
.divClass span{
    /*your style here*/
 }
```

By doing this you should be able to control the styles.

Checking the code of the respective files would be better in order to help you.

Comment: The spans in the Login page are external and I have also no access to them. So the "className" cannot be solution. I have tried making different css files, but that didn't help . In some way they are linking with each other, without me including them on top of the page.

Comment: Where are you defining css class? And where are you importing that css? 
Seems like you are defining style for span globally. Maybe you have reference to that css in index.html, or the “main” of your application. But it is hard to say without an example of the code.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/hAZ-3TCMuOyP that is the structure of my app. and here is the imports https://prnt.sc/0iNlaBjoENiV

Comment: Are maybe the span styles defined in App.css too? (Which I suppose is used in App.js, which is the main).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I found out that your span styling applies to both the login page and the profile page. This is because you have globally targeted the span for styling in css , don't target the span globally, add a class for your span on the login page and style them

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, I think you can try these.

Add parent class to your login.css file:

```
.parentClass span {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px;
    color: red;
    display: none;
}
```

Or add a class name to your span in login.js.

```
<span className="spanClass">
    // your style here
</span>
```

login.css file

```
.spanClass {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px;
    color: red;
    display: none;
}
```